# Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/launch_image'

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I am trying to put in am image for my splash screen in my flutter app but i am getting the error `Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/launcher_icon'`  . what exactly is wrong with my code. This is my the code in my launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
     <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launcher_icon" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: image of the code]

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, it cannot be done in that way. You have to list your image in the assets in pubspec.yaml.

If you are using flutter in android Studio, it is not possible.

It doesn't have the structure files as Android Studio.

And lastly try to create a flutter project correctly. It is an Android Studio Project.